# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javapasswords in Linux

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime, javac

i have code like this,

```
import javapasswordsdk.PSDKPassword;
import javapasswordsdk.PSDKPasswordRequest;
import javapasswordsdk.exceptions.PSDKException;

etc.............
```

I am getting below error, it is taking javapasswordsdk.PSDKPassword;
javapasswordsdk.PSDKPasswordRequest but not taking javapasswordsdk.exceptions.PSDKException

All these class in one jar file. My question is why it is taking to why cant it other.

please clarify asap.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javapasswordsdk/exceptions/PSDKException
    at beans.MigrateData.main(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javapasswordsdk.exceptions.PSDKException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this `compiler-errors` when you're getting an exception at *execution time*?

Comment: "why it is taking to why cant it other." - I have no clue what you are saying here.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your `beans.MigrateData` class is in one jar file, and the `javapasswordsdk` classes are in another. So you probably want:

```
java -cp beans.jar:javapasswordsdk.jar beans.MigrateData
```

(or something similar).

Basically, you need to make sure that the `javapasswordsdk` classes are on the classpath at execution time. We don't really know how you're trying to run your code or how it's packaged, so the above is just a guess - but you should be able to adapt it appropriately.

EDIT: Now that we can see how you're running it, the problem is that you're using the wrong separator in your classpath. On Unix you use `:` rather than `;` to separate entries:

```
Windows: java -cp jar1;jar2;jar3
Unix:    java -cp jar1:jar2:jar3
```

Comment: thank u for reply. i am running it in batch file like this         java -cp .;EDMS5CommandLine.jar;./lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar;./lib/ojdbc14.jar;./lib/javapasswordsdk.jar;./lib/sqljdbc.jar;./lib/mail.jar;./lib/activation.jar beans.MigrateData %2               beans.MigrateData in edms.jar file. and javapasswordsdk in lib folder. working this fine in windows. but in linux not working. checked jar all present. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2369841: Yes, you're using the wrong classpath separator. It's `:` on Unix, not `;`. Note that if you'd included information about how you were running the code in your original question, we'd have got to the answer much quicker.

Comment: Thank You So much Jon. I rechecked, i have two diff bats one for windows and other for linux. i checked again in linux file only for that jar i misplaced ;. Thank you. This was my first thread in all java sites. Good result. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your required jar are in ClassPath: Because [NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear: `javapasswordsdk.exceptions.PSDKException;` cannot be found in the classpath.

Therefore it seems that the class is not in the jar you think it is in, or that jar is not properly added to the classpath.